# Time differences in Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

In a Big Data context I have a time series **S1=(t1, t2, t3 ...)** sorted in an ascending order. I would like to produce a series of time differences: **S2=(t2-t1, t3-t2 ...)**

1. Is there a way to do this in Apache Pig? Short of a very
   inefficient self-join, I do not see one.
2. If not, what would be an good way to do this suitable for large amounts
   of data?

Comment: Can you sample input data and is the no of fields constant across records ?

Comment: @MuraliRao Pig has a SAMPLE functionality: see [Pig Manual](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SAMPLE) allowing you to specify the percentage you want to sample. In this particular case I do know that the time series is strictly increasing, but I'm not sure it makes a difference. The key assumption is that it's already sorted.

Comment: I meant input test data to try this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. S1 = Generate Id,Timestamp i.e. from t1...tn
2. S2 = Generate Id,Timestamp i.e. from t2...tn
3. S3 = Join S1 by Id,S2 by Id
4. S4 = Extract S1.Timestamp,S2.Timestamp,(S2.TimeStamp - S1.TimeStamp)

**Edit**

**Sample Data**

```
2014-02-19T01:03:37
2014-02-26T01:03:39
2014-02-28T01:03:45
2014-04-01T01:04:22
2014-05-11T01:06:02
2014-06-30T01:08:56
```

**Script**

```
s1 = LOAD 'test2.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (t:chararray);
s11 = foreach s1 generate ToDate(t) as t1;
s1_new = rank s11;

s2 = LOAD 'test2.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (t:chararray);
s22 = foreach s2 generate ToDate(t) as t1;
s2_new = rank s22;

-- Filter records by excluding the 1 ranked row and rank the new data
ss = FILTER s2_new by (rank_s22 > 1);
ss_new = rank ss;

s3 = join s1_new by rank_s11,ss_new by rank_ss;
s4 = foreach s3 generate DaysBetween(ss_new::t1,s1_new::t1) as time_diff;

DUMP s4;
```

[image: Difference in Days]

Comment: I think this may work! I'm not sure how to easily do step 2 in Pig though.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include sample data,script and output.Note that you might have to format the output to match your requirements.The output is the difference in days between successive timestamps.

Comment: very good and complete solution; cannot mark it as such at the moment due to my rank. Thanks!